# Fatal signal 4 when run app on Android API 19 emulator

Tags: android, android-studio, fatal-error

I tried to run my app on android emulator 19 API but my app crash after the splash screen.
This is the erros:
[image]

i using sdk min 19 with emulator nexus 5 api 19

what can i do to run my app?

tnx a lot

Comment: Please put some code from your splash screen

Comment: @AnkitAman this is the splash screen of the android i only change the images in xml/config.xml

Comment: this is the debugger logs:https://pastebin.com/LhR48fLx